# Minimal DFA accepting strings whose length is divisible by $x$ or $y$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Consider the language of all strings whose length is divisible by either $x$ or $y$, where $x,y \geq 1$.

After trying various values of $x$ and $y$, I noticed made the following observation:

> If one of $x,y$ is a multiple of the other, then the minimal DFA contains $\min(x,y)$ states, and otherwise it contains $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$ states.

Is this true for all values of $x$ and $y$?

Also, what happens if we replace the condition "divisible by either $x$ or $y$" with the condition "divisible by both $x$ and $y$"?

Comment: I assume MDFA is the *minimal* DFA? This is not a standard acronym.

Comment: The answer for the AND case is $\mathsf{lcm}(x,y)$, since a number is divisible by both $x$ and $y$ iff it is divisible by their LCM.

Comment: Will it be true for all x and y?

Comment: Yes, this is a well-known fact from elementary number theory, which you can try to prove as an exercise.

Comment: It is also well-known that the MDFA for all words whose length is divisible by $m$ is a cycle of $m$ states. This can be proved in many ways, for example Myhill-Nerode theory or the pumping lemma.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\operatorname{gcd}(x,y) = g$, and suppose that $x,y > g$. If there is a minimal DFA for the language with $n$ states, then according to the pumping lemma, there is $1 \leq m \leq n$ such that the following holds: $\ell \geq n$ is a length of words in the language iff $\ell + m$ is a length of words in the language, that is:

> For all $\ell \geq n$: $(x \mid \ell \text{ or } y \mid \ell)$ iff $(x \mid \ell+m \text{ or } y \mid \ell+m)$.

Let $\ell \geq n$ be some multiple of $x$. Then $x \mid \ell$, hence either $x \mid \ell+m$ or $y \mid \ell+m$, which implies that $g \mid \ell$ and $g \mid \ell+m$, and so $g \mid m$.

Suppose that $x \nmid m$. Let $\ell \geq n$ be such that $\ell \equiv -m \pmod{x}$ and $\ell \equiv g \pmod{y}$; there exists such $\ell$ since $g \mid m$. Then $x\nmid \ell$, $y\nmid\ell$ (since $y > g$), but $x\mid \ell+m$, and we reach a contradiction. Therefore $x \mid m$. Similarly, $y \mid m$. Therefore $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) \mid m$, implying that $n \geq m \geq \operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$ (since $m > 0$).

Conversely, it is easy to construct a DFA for the language with $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$ states, showing that this is the number of states in a minimal DFA, assuming that $x,y > g$.

If $x = g$ or $y = g$, then the language consists of all words whose lengths are a multiple of $g = \min(x,y)$, and so the minimal DFA contains $\min(x,y)$ states.

Finally, if we replace *or* with *and* in the definition, then we get the language of all words whose lengths are a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$, whose minimal DFA contains $\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$ states.